# SOCI ODBC Connection ERROR

Tags: c++, database, odbc, soci

I am trying to connect the SOCI library to my database but keep on receiving this error on my VS compiler output.

My code is :

```
{
  try
  { 
    backend_factory const& backEnd = odbc;
    std::string const & connectString = "DSN=CVD_SQL_connection_2016b_64bit";
    session sql(backEnd, connectString);

  }
  catch (const std::exception& e)
  {

    cerr << e.what();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The error warnings are the following:

[image]

Can someone please guide me about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have also looked into that what we need for  SQLDriverConnect but can't seem to understand. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: Search Stack Overflow on how to set the compiler switch _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. THere are plenty of questions and answers on this.

Comment: I have added that to the preprocessor. My problem is that I am not too sure what parameters I need to set to connect to my ODBC ms_sql. The website guide is the following [link](http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/3.2/backends/odbc.html). Can you help me with this guide? I do apologize as it seems simple but I  can't seem to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

or

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
```

to suppress the warning.

Or use:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES 1
```

to let the compiler automatically replace `strcpy()` with `strcpy_s()` for you. See [here for more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/secure-template-overloads)

---

To connect to ODBC you can use a `connection_parameters` object to pass the connection details as follows:

```
connection_parameters parameters("odbc", "DSN=CVD_SQL_connection_2016b_64bit");
parameters.set_option(odbc_option_driver_complete, "0");
session sql(parameters);
```

Don't forget to include the `soci-odbc.h`